# Can a HTML5 button be used to navigate to another local HTML5 page? If yes kindly share it with us

Tags: html

I know Buttons can be href to other websites. But What if I want to navigate to a local page (ex: page.html saved in the same folder as the html5 document containing the original button) ?

Comment: First try yourself and ask here if you are facing any problem.

Comment: Are you aware of the option called googling?!

Comment: You should try yourself and share the code if you can't make it.

Comment: I tried href myself. Can I post my code in the comment section? Mikelis If I can Stack Overflow I can obviously google. I am sure you will find better questions to answer !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like the other comments said, this question could be googled in 2sec.

Use relative references. So if I have a folder with page1.html and page2.html, in my page1.html code I'd have a button/link referencing the name of the html file I want to open upon click. Example:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="page2.html"> Page2 </a>
```

If page2.html was in a folder in that directory called "foo" then you'd reference:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="foo/page2.html"> Page2 </a>
```

Note the class "btn" and "btn-primary" is bootstrap button class.